How to prevent from auto reloading in html page?
I am making a chatting application using spring boot 3 and i use web socket to make connection. I've created a web page with 2 buttons "Start Chat" and "Close Chat". When i click the "Start Chat" button it adds html codes into an html element(id="chat"). This html code is from "https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket". And when i click the "Close Chat" button it removes the html codes from the element. My issue:
When i click the Start Chat button and Connect it works well. After closing, if i open the chat again and click Connect the page is reloaded. I don't want this reloading when i try to connect chat again.
(Note: After clearing the chat elements from page i also call disconnect() function from webSocket.js )
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@stomp/stompjs@7.0.0/bundles/stomp.umd.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div th:insert="components/header :: header"></div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <button onclick="openChat()" class="btn btn-primary m-3">Start Chatting</button>
            <button onclick="closeChat()" class="btn btn-primary m-3">Close Chat</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="row m-3" id="chat"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function closeChat() {
        const chatElement = document.getElementById("main-content");
        chatElement.remove();
        disconnect();
        const scriptElement = document.getElementById("webSocketJs");
        if (scriptElement) {
            scriptElement.remove();
        }
    }

    function openChat() {
        event.preventDefault();
        const chatElement = document.getElementById("chat");
        const content =
            `<div id="main-content" className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <form className="form-inline">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="connect">WebSocket connection:</label>
                                <button id="connect" className="btn btn-default" type="submit" >Connect</button>
                                <button id="disconnect" className="btn btn-default" type="submit"
                                        disabled="disabled">Disconnect
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <form className="form-inline">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="name">What is your name?</label>
                                <input type="text" id="name" className="form-control" placeholder="Your name here..."/>
                            </div>
                            <button id="send" className="btn btn-default" type="submit">Send</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <table id="conversation" className="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Greetings</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="greetings">
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
        chatElement.innerHTML = content;

        const scriptElement = document.getElementById("webSocketJs");
        if (!scriptElement) {
            let webSocketScript = document.createElement('script');
            webSocketScript.setAttribute('src', '/js/webSocket.js');
            webSocketScript.setAttribute('id', 'webSocketJs');
            document.body.appendChild(webSocketScript);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>

const stompClient = new StompJs.Client({
    brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket'
});

stompClient.onConnect = (frame) => {
    setConnected(true);
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', (greeting) => {
        showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
    });
};

stompClient.onWebSocketError = (error) => {
    console.error('Error with websocket', error);
};

stompClient.onStompError = (frame) => {
    console.error('Broker reported error: ' + frame.headers['message']);
    console.error('Additional details: ' + frame.body);
};

function setConnected(connected) {
    $("#connect").prop("disabled", connected);
    $("#disconnect").prop("disabled", !connected);
    if (connected) {
        $("#conversation").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#conversation").hide();
    }
    $("#greetings").html("");
}

function connect() {
    stompClient.activate();
}

function disconnect() {
    stompClient.deactivate();
    setConnected(false);
    console.log("Disconnected");
}

function sendName() {
    stompClient.publish({
        destination: "/app/hello",
        body: JSON.stringify({'name': $("#name").val()})
    });
}

function showGreeting(message) {
    $("#greetings").append("<tr><td>" + message + "</td></tr>");
}

$(function () {
    $("form").on('submit', (e) => e.preventDefault());
    $( "#connect" ).click(() => connect());
    $( "#disconnect" ).click(() => disconnect());
    $( "#send" ).click(() => sendName());
});

First one is my html page, and second one is webSocket.js file.

Your webSocket.js script is only loaded one time, when you first start the chat. So your event handlers are connected to the buttons then. Not so when you start the chat for the second time. This means that $("form").on('submit', (e) => e.preventDefault()); is not activated and your form is simply submitted.

Okay i understood the problem but how can i solve it? I mean is there any way to load webSocket.js script without reloading whole page

Put your event handlers in a function, and then call that function in openChat() after you added the HTML for the chat box to the page and loaded webSocket.js, but do it every time.
